# Local attributes/variable in inherited classes

Tags: javascript, variables, inheritance, local

I have a set of classes I derive from a base class as following (for example):

```
function Base(){}
Base.prototype.foo = function() { alert("base"); };

function Derived() {}

Derived.prototype = Object.create( Base.prototype );
Derived.prototype.foo = function() { alert("overridden"); };  

var b = new Base();
var d = new Derived();

b.foo();
d.foo();
```

I would like to add variables to the base class (not Java static-like variables, but those with separate values per class instance). Yet, I would like the `Derived` class to be able to access them too.

I am no Javascript specialist, I have been playing around a little, but I can't get it to work. Is this possible to achieve this? Or should I implement setter and getters?

Comment: You should implement _not tagging your titles_, ta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example:

```
function Base( name ){
    this.name = name;
}


function Derived( name, type ) {
    Base.call( this, name );
    this.type = type;
}
Derived.prototype = Object.create( Base.prototype );


var b = new Base( 'Peter' );
var d = new Derived( 'John', 2 );
```

So, the `Base` class defines one instance member - `'name'`. The `Derived` class defines one *additional* instance member - `'type'`.

The key part is invoking the `Base` constructor inside the `Derived` constructor invocation - so, internally, you "set up" the instance as if it were a `Base` instance (you pass in the required arguments), and then you augment the instance with the additional stuff defined only for `Derived` instances.

So, in my example above, `b` has one own property - `'name'`, whereas `d` has two own properties - `'name'`, and `'type'`.

Comment: Worth noting that *Object.create* is ES5, though [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) provides a work around for older implementations.

Comment: @RobG That polyfill is nice, but the easiest solution is of course to just include ES5-shim for `IE lt 9`. (It also includes a [superior polyfill](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js#L574).)